# Representing the pthread function call types with LLVM type builder

Tags: compiler-construction, pthreads, llvm, compiler-optimization

I'm interested in paralleling loops in LLVM, and I want to use the type builder when importing the pthread functions.

Pthread_join has a fair simple signature, but Pthread_create has the signature:

```
 int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

At the moment I have:

```
FunctionType *pthreadJoinTy = TypeBuilder<int(int,void *,void*(void*) (void*),void*),false>::get(C);
M.getOrInsertFunction("pthread_create", pthreadCreateTy);
```

But LLVM isn't happy with my attempt at building pthreadCreateTy. The three build errors it spits out are:

> error: ‘parameter’ declared as function returning a function
>       (void*),void*),false>::get(c);
>
> error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
>       (void*),void*),false>::get(c);
>
> error: provided for ‘template class
>   llvm::TypeBuilder’  template class
>   TypeBuilder {};

What is the correct TypeBuilder code to use here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting thrown by the C declaration `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`. This is just a function (called `start_routine`) that takes a void pointer and returns a void pointer.

The way you described this in `TypeBuilder` is syntactically wrong: `void*(void*) (void*)`. You've added an extra `(void*)`.

The right `TypeBuilder` is `void*(void*)`.

But generally, the declaration you're trying to build is wrong anyway. Looking at what Clang does, the declaration you're aiming for is this:

```
%union.pthread_attr_t = type { i64, [48 x i8] }
declare i32 @pthread_create(i64*, %union.pthread_attr_t*, i8* (i8*)*, i8*)
```